# how to make a for loops of some command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I’m just wondering is there anyway to create 1000 folders and into each of them be 1000 files and into each file written some text for example like this

```
Folder0001
    |
    File0001.txt
        |
        MY Text 0001

Folder0002
    |
    File0002.txt
        |
        MY Text 0002
.
.
.
Folder1000
    |
    File1000.txt
        |
        MY Text 1000
```

here is my bash code

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`; do 
    mkdir folder"$i" | echo "My Text $i" >folder"$i"/file"$i"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$ mkdir {0001..1000}
$ for d in *; do echo "Some Text ${d}" > ${d}/${d}.txt; done
```

Comment: @Freeman *I want it via pipe.* What kind of requirement is that? Either you need help with your problem or you don't. Pipes don't make sense here.

Comment: @Freeman, Why do you need it in pipe ?. Because, `mkdir`, `mv`..won't read from `STDIN`.

Comment: @Freeman, It is not doing anything with `PIPE`. Still `mkdir` is not reading input from `STDIN` (Ex: `echo '...' | mkdir ...`). But, the command `mkdir ...` is executed and new directory created.

Comment: Because, Shell will create all commands as separate process, then making a `PIPE` between processes. So that `echo` command output will read by `mkdir`. Now, `mkdir <dirname>` is a process and it will create a directory. Again, It doesn't read anything from `PIPE`. It's done the job. Then, It will exit.

Answer (score 3):

Leverage brace expansion to get the range, and then iterate over it using `for`, create necessary stuffs along the way:

```
for i in {0001..1000}; do mkdir Folder"$i" && echo "My Text $i" >Folder"$i"/File"$i"; done
```

Expanded:

```
for i in {0001..1000}; do 
    mkdir Folder"$i" && echo "My Text $i" >Folder"$i"/File"$i"
done
```

Comment: @Freeman `mkdir`, `mv` do not take input via STDIN, so piping won't help here.